# как определить функцию, чтобы отсчет "e" шел с конца на начало. то есть цифра один должна быть найдена первой, а не пятой по счету?

Tags: python, list

```
def search_reverse(L, x):
    n = len(L)-1
    for e in range(n,-1, -1):
        if L[e]==x:
            print(x, "найден в списке с ", e + 1, " раза")
            return True
    print( x, " не найден в списке" )
    return False



lst = [4, 7, 2, 3, 1]
result = search_reverse( lst, 1)
print( result )
```

Comment: [Что делать с ответами на вопрос?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 1):

У вас так и происходит. `e` принимает начальное значение `4`. Поэтому выводится

```
найден в списке с 5 раза
```

Сделайте

```
print(x, "найден в списке с ", len(L) - e - 1, " раза")
```

Comment: спасибо, получилось

Comment: Если ответ вам помог, примите его (зелёная галочка слева).